# adding an item to lazy row using ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

here is my scenario, i want to be able to add items to a lazy row, i have a card when i click on it the user will be prompt to select a date an click on the positive button the new item will be added to the lazy row,i have tried to add event handler and use ViewModel to add and observe any changes in the list but it didn't work for me.
here what i want to achieve:

> ViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class HabitsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val habitUseCases: HabitUseCases,
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {
    private val remindersState = MutableStateFlow(ReminderListState())
     //i used to observe the state of the list
     fun consumableState()  = remindersState.asStateFlow()
 fun onEvent(event: HabitsEvent) {
         when(event) {
       is HabitsEvent.AddItem -> {
                val currentState = remindersState.value
                val items = currentState.reminders.toMutableList().apply {
                    //here i'm confused how to get the state of the value of the current date
                    add()
                }.toList()

                remindersState.value = remindersState.value.copy(
                    reminders = items
                )
            }
}
```

> Event class and data class to hold the list.

```
sealed class HabitsEvent() {
    object AddItem: HabitsEvent()
}

data class ReminderListState(val reminders : List<String> = emptyList())
```

> LazyRow Composable

```
@Composable
fun RemindMeComponent(
    modifier : Modifier = Modifier,
    onClick : () -> Unit,
    habitsViewModel: HabitsViewModel = viewModel()
) {


    val reminderState = habitsViewModel.consumableState().collectAsState()

    Row(
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        RemindMeCard(
            onClick = onClick,
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Add
        )
        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp)
        )
        LazyRow() {
            items(reminderState.value.reminders) {
                reminderState.value.reminders.forEach { date ->
                    Column {
                        RemindMeCard(
                            onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.RingVolume,
                        )
                        Text(
                            text = date,
                            fontSize = 12.sp
                        )
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

MaterialDailog positive button:

```
//Here i shoudl be able to add new item to the list. 
         positiveButton(
                                    text = "Ok",
                                    onClick = {
                                        habitsViewModel.onEvent(
                                     HabitsEvent.AddItem
                                 )                                    }
                                )
```

the final result that i'm looking for:

[image: GIF_description]

Answer (score 0):

the major problem i found using MutableStateFlow or MutableStateFlow,
when i add new value to the reminderState.value the variable hasn't been able to recompose successfully, and even when i read the documentation MutableState is actually mutable value holder which can be observed and if this Mutable State holds a mutable list it won't be observed because the mutable list by default is not observable that's why i was confused when i add new item i'm not able to see any changes in the Lazy Row items, and that's the problem using mutable state with mutable list, and here is a solution example:

> ViewModel.kt

```
private val _reminders = mutableStateOf<String>() 
val reminders : List<String> = _reminders
//fun to add element to the list. 
     fun addElement(reminder : String)
        {
            _reminders.add(reminder)
        }
```

the type of the variable now is actually a snapshot state list and this type can be easily converted to immutable list.

> inside the lazyRow composable function:

```
//gets the list of elements. 
val reminderState = habitsViewModel.reminders
```

instead of adding all the items in every re composition that will fire duplicate `items()` in the list instead i used `item {}` to Add a single item using `forEach {}` this will avoid duplicates and it will iterate through each element and accordingly will add new item.

> LazyRow composable

```
   LazyRow() {
            if (reminderState.isNotEmpty())
                reminderState.forEach { date ->
                    item {
                        Column {
                            RemindMeCard(
                                onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                                imageVector = Icons.Default.RingVolume,
                            )
                            Text(
                                text = date,
                                fontSize = 12.sp
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

any suggestion for better performance will be appreciated.